# Can i delete a message from a blocked caller. Just a certain one not all of them?

Tags: sms-blocking

Can you delete just certain messages you get from a blocked call?

Answer (score 1):

On most messaging apps, if you tap and hold on a message in *any* conversation, it will give you an option to delete the message. However, the deletion only occurs on your phone, not the phone on the other end.